# How to get previous row value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table called DcdItems in which 3 columns are there. In the Status column we can store 3 types of data which is (InProgress, PreProduction,Released). ReleaseDate date will be stored when the Status is in Released mode.

My requirement is when Status is inProgress or Preproduction and there is only 1 Row then ReleaseDate column should be NULL`` and if Status is inProgress or Preproduction and there is more than 1 row then it will pick previous row's ReleasedDate column. If status is Released then simply it will fetch original data which is nothing but its own Releasedate.

| Number | DcdStatus | ReleaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | inProgress | Null |
| 15 | Rleased | 13/09/2023 |

In this above case I need to get previous row's date to show inProgress row

| Number | DcdStatus | ReleaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | inProgress | NULL |

| Number | DcdStatus | ReleaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 343 | Rleased | 10/09/2023 |

I don't need all the row data in 1 report, I only need a single row which is the latest and updated row.

I am trying this below query. It's working fine for all the condition but when status is inProgress and it has only 1 row; it's not getting any data.

```
@";WITH _cteDCDReleaseDate1
AS(
    SELECT              Number, ReleaseDate
    FROM                [dse].[DcdItems]
    WHERE               DcdStatus='Released'
)


select
                di.[Number] as [OLAID],
                di.[DcdStatus] as [Status],
                di.[DcdVersion] as [Version],
                CAST(CASE WHEN di.DcdStatus in ('InProgress','PreProduction') THEN T2.ReleaseDate ELSE di.ReleaseDate END as Datetime) as [LastUpdated],

        from    [dse].[DcdItems] di
        INNER JOIN _cteDCDReleaseDate1 T2 ON T2.Number=di.Number
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, and emphasis on minimal... i.e. reduce the complexity down to the bare minimum to demonstrate the issue

Comment: `where di.Id = {0}` looks like application code and *also* looks like injection; I *hope* not.

Comment: @ThomA forget about di.id .. everything is working but getting issue when status is inprogress and have npw previous row.

Comment: @DaleK i just reduced query.please check now

Comment: Injection works, *sure*, but it's not safe.